# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session ,says no getter, but my getter /setters exists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I dont know if it has something to do with my hibernate layer . Can you please help . I googled but was not able to figure that out

Contact class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="EMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE")
private String telephone;


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{contactId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("contactId") Integer contactId,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println("I was here");
    Contact contact = contactService.getContact(contactId);

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashedMap();
    model.put("contact", contact);

    return new ModelAndView("contact_edit", model);
}
```

jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="contact">

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstname">
                    <spring:message code="label.firstname" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname">
                    <spring:message code="label.lastname" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">
                    <spring:message code="label.email" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="telephone">
                    <spring:message code="label.telephone" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                value="<spring:message code="label.addcontact"/>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Invalid property 'firstname' of bean class [net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0]: Getter for property 'firstname' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'firstname' of bean class [net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0]: Getter for property 'firstname' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:845)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:255)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspService(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:761)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0.getFirstname(Contact_$$_javassist_0.java)
    ... 56 more
Sep 14, 2012 4:41:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0.getFirstname(Contact_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:761)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:255)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspService(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Sep 14, 2012 4:41:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Spring3HibernateMaven] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/contact_edit.jsp at line 50

47:         <table>
48:         
49:             <tr>
50:                 <td><form:label path="firstname">
51:                         <spring:message code="label.firstname" />
52:                     </form:label></td>
53:                 <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0.getFirstname(Contact_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:761)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:255)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspService(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

---------------- edit1 ---------
As mentioned here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

my pom.xml dependencies for version info:

```
 <dependencies>

    <!-- Junit library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- taglibs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSON jackson dependency to return JSON from controllers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is not related to your getter, but the fact that by the time you are rendering the results, the Hibernate session has been closed (that's what the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` implies.

To avoid this, you can either

- Switch of lazy loading for your entity (i.e. Hibernate will populate the full entity when you load it inside your controller, when the session is active)
- Or use the [OpenSessionInView](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern, which will keep the Hibernate session open until the rendering of your JSP has completed.

EDIT:

Spring provides support for the OpenSessionInView pattern through the [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html).

Comment: thanks !! so it isn't that spring mvc should handle this automatically as I am using spring's form tag , and have not opened session manually??

Comment: I added this to web.xml : <filter>
     <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>        
 </filter> was of no help ...

Comment: Have you also added a filter mapping?

Comment: And just to double check, which version of Spring and Hibernate are you using?

Comment: can you please check my edited post for all your information. Now it is gving me file not found for applicationContext.xml, I know listner expects it , so I created file but don't know what to configure there ....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16718/discussion-between-manmohan-vyas-and-beny23)

Comment: A well written article about the Spring's OpenSessionInViewFilter is [here](http://blog.gmorales.net/2012/03/how-to-solve-orghibernatelazyinitializa.html)

Comment: I just faced the exact same message. **BUT**, for other to know, I was eagerly loading object dependencies. Underlying problem was a foreign key constraint that couldn't be satisfied. By adding `lazy="false"` in my mapping file, I obtained real reason of failure : `INFO: Error performing load command
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: `

Answer (score -2):

Also check the respective table is having data or not. It throws "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session" when the table does not have data.

Comment: I doubt that it will throw error on empty data, do you have some evidence to support your answer?

Comment: This never happen if no data.